# Getting ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :driver_path) using Kimurai, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kimurai

I am trying to use the kimurai gem to try and web scrape but running into issues. I am following along with https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework#crawl-method and have installed web drivers, but when calling my scraper class I get the following error and stack trace:

```
WwozScraper.crawl!
I, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420]  INFO -- wwoz_scraper: Spider: started: wwoz_scraper
D, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420] DEBUG -- wwoz_scraper: BrowserBuilder (selenium_chrome): created browser instance
D, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420] DEBUG -- wwoz_scraper: BrowserBuilder (selenium_chrome): enabled native headless_mode
I, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420]  INFO -- wwoz_scraper: Browser: started get request to: https://www.wwoz.org/programs/playlists
I, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420]  INFO -- wwoz_scraper: Info: visits: requests: 1, responses: 0
I, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420]  INFO -- wwoz_scraper: Browser: driver selenium_chrome has been destroyed
F, [2022-08-15 22:43:20 -0400#49087] [M: 3420] FATAL -- wwoz_scraper: Spider: stopped: {:spider_name=>"wwoz_scraper", :status=>:failed, :error=>"#<ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :driver_path>", :environment=>"development", :start_time=>2022-08-15 22:43:20.673033 -0400, :stop_time=>2022-08-15 22:43:20.795284 -0400, :running_time=>"0s", :visits=>{:requests=>1, :responses=>0}, :items=>{:sent=>0, :processed=>0}, :events=>{:requests_errors=>{}, :drop_items_errors=>{}, :custom=>{}}}
```

Here is my class:

```
require 'kimurai'


class WwozScraper < Kimurai::Base
  @name= 'wwoz_scraper'
  @start_urls = ['https://www.wwoz.org/programs/playlists']
  @engine = :selenium_chrome

  def scrape_page
      doc = browser.current_response
  end

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    scrape_page
  end
end
```

Ruby version `2.7.4`

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.5', '>= 6.1.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'kimurai'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: FWIW I was able to run your spider using 2.7.3, but not 2.7.4 (though I get a different error than you did). There are multiple issues open about 3.x support and the gem doesn't appear to be actively maintained currently.